# gnuradio error: found character '%' that cannot start any token

Tags: yaml, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I get this error when I run GNU Radio Companion. Of course, the multi_rtl_source.block.yml block doesn't work and doesn't show up in the menu:

```
    ERROR:gnuradio.grc.core.platform:Error while loading /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/platform.py", line 169, in build_library
    data = cache.get_or_load(file_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/cache.py", line 66, in get_or_load
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 258, in fetch_more_tokens
    raise ScannerError("while scanning for the next token", None,
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml", line 33, column 5
ERROR:gnuradio.grc.core.platform:while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml", line 33, column 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/platform.py", line 169, in build_library
    data = cache.get_or_load(file_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnuradio/grc/core/cache.py", line 66, in get_or_load
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 258, in fetch_more_tokens
    raise ScannerError("while scanning for the next token", None,
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml", line 33, column 5
```

I also get this:

```
>>> Check: /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml
>>> FlowGraph Error: while scanning for the next token
found character '%' that cannot start any token
  in "/usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/multi_rtl_source.block.yml", line 33, column 5
```

There is an YAML directive in line 33, column 5:

```
-   id: sync_gain0
    label: Ch0: Sync RF Gain (dB)
    category: Synchronization
    dtype: real
    default: 10
    hide: \\
    %if nchan() > n: <== line 33
part
    %else:
all
   %endif
```

full code of multi_rtl_source.block.yml can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/4YSNJS9Q)

There is an [article](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/YAML_GRC) in the GNU Radio wiki in which it is written that you can place YAML dicrices in GRC blocks. So where this error came from and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you share all your modifications preferably in a github fork of the multi_rtl project?

Comment: @Vasil Velichkov I uploaded the project to github. I haven't changed anything in README and in the license, but I think I can do that if the project is under the GPL license. https://github.com/antoniprzybylik/multi-rtl

Comment: You should not change the license. Instead of creating a new repository it would be better to [fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) the original repository. This way your fork would be linked to the original repository, you can make changes in it and once you are satisfied you can create a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request) to contribute your changes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     hide: \\
> ```

In YAML the correct way to have multi-line string is using `>` or `|` specifiers (see https://yaml-multiline.info/) and not `\\`, for example

```
    hide: |
```

Alternatively you can write the hide condition on a single line like this

```
    hide: ${'part' if nchan > 0 else 'all'}
```

And here is how to fix it in `gen_multi_rtl_block.py`

```
@@ -104,57 +100,32 @@ template_p = """\
     category: Synchronization
     dtype: real
     default: 10
-    hide: &
-    ${"%"} if nchan() > n:
-part
-    ${"%"} else:
-all
-    ${"%"} endif
+    hide: ${'$'}{'part' if nchan > ${n} else 'all'}
```